# IntelliJ - running as sudo throough JetBrains Toolbox

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to start intelliJ from Toolbox and manage it from there but need intelliJ to run as sudo. Does anyne know if it's possible?

Edit:
I need this because on my local machine my application cannot create folders for which normally root is needed - saving logs to specific folder in system.

Comment: Why don't you just make that _specific_ folder non-root user writable?

Comment: Just did ant it works! Put is as an aswer and will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared to run JetBrains App from Toolbox with root, it's easier for you to change that *specific* folder non-root user writable, with something like

```
sudo chown <user> <folder>
```

However, this may cause some security problem if that *specific* folder is somewhere system wide related, for example inside `/usr/bin/`, so it's better not to do so. But if you *really* need that, you may try to gain `sudo` privilege for example use `gksudo` while running your application.